# how can i make anaconda spyder code completion work again after installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, code-completion

I am data scientist in beijing and working with anaconda in win7
but after I pip installed tensorflow v1.4,code completion of my IDE spyder in anaconda not work, before anything of code completion function is work perfectly.

Now even I uninstall tensorflow,code completion function of spyder still not work. Any help?

**my envirment:**
win7
anaconda3 v5.0 for win64 (py3.6)
tensorflow v1.4 for win (tf_nightly-1.4.0.dev20171006-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl)

So two question:

1 How can i fix it so to make anaconda3 spyder code completion work again?

2 After uninstall tensorflow, anaconda3 spyder code completion still not work, what can I do?

Comment: BTW , after I pip installed tensorflow v1.4 ,the code-completor of ipython console of spyder  still work ,but it not work on editor

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a know issue. Unfortunately, we don't know how to fix it yet.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba
I don't know ipython how to parse tf and other classes, can we use ipython  config file or parse system in spyder ,then fix this issue?

Does spyder use Jedi  or repo to parse package?

Answer (score 0):

I try pip rope_py3k、jedi and readline, and reset the set of tool, but all are not useful.
and my Spyder code editing area also can not be automatically completed after the installation of tensorflow, I have re-installed again and found the same problem.
However,when I re-installed all envs except tensorflow,it can work!! 
 My environment is win10, anaconda3.5, python3.6.3, tensorflow1.4.
Did you resolve it?And I hope you can teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have to use a temporary alternative, I installed anaconda version without an installed tensorflow in anaconda's envs. And I use it when I don't use tensorflow. I hope this question can be complement answered, please attent my answer.

Comment: NOW i code in st3  ,and run in spyder ( I  need its variable viewer to debug my programe)